# Custom widget crash when I insert it inside a Column / Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

When I include the Tutorial class that I create inside the children of a Column class I get this error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone XR in debug mode...
Starting Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           20.7s
Syncing files to device iPhone XR...
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
flutter: Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height.
flutter: Viewports expand in the cross axis to fill their container and constrain their children to match
flutter: their extent in the cross axis. In this case, a horizontal viewport was given an unlimited amount of
flutter: vertical space in which to expand.
flutter:
flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
flutter: #0      RenderViewport.performResize.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1170:15)
flutter: #1      RenderViewport.performResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1182:6)
flutter: #2      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:9)
flutter: #3      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
flutter: #4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #5      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
flutter: #6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #7      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
flutter: #8      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #9      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
flutter: #10     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #11     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
flutter: #12     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #13     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:510:15)
flutter: #14     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #15     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:738:15)
flutter: #16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #17     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
flutter: #18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #19     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
flutter: #20     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #21     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
flutter: #22     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #23     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:510:15)
flutter: #24     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #25     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
flutter: #26     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #27     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
flutter: #28     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #29     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
flutter: #30     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #31     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
flutter: #32     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #33     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
flutter: #34     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #35     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
flutter: #36     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2881:13)
flutter: #37     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #38     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:510:15)
flutter: #39     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #40     __RenderTheatre&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
flutter: #41     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #42     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
flutter: #43     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #44     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
flutter: #45     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #46     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
flutter: #47     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #48     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
flutter: #49     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #50     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
flutter: #51     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
flutter: #52     RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:147:13)
flutter: #53     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1509:7)
flutter: #54     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:768:18)
flutter: #55     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:281:19)
flutter: #56     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:677:13)
flutter: #57     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:219:5)
flutter: #58     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:990:15)
flutter: #59     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:930:9)
flutter: #60     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:751:7)
flutter: #62     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:382:19)
flutter: #63     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:416:5)
flutter: #64     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)
flutter: (elided one frame from package dart:async)
flutter:
flutter: The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired:
flutter:   RenderViewport#64551 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:   creator: Viewport ← _ScrollableScope ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#608ab] ← Semantics ← Listener ←
flutter:   _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#19222] ←
flutter:   _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#0390f] ← Scrollable ← NotificationListener<ScrollNotification> ←
flutter:   PageView ← Stack ← ⋯
flutter:   parentData: <none> (can use size)
flutter:   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=414.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
flutter:   size: MISSING
flutter:   axisDirection: right
flutter:   crossAxisDirection: down
flutter:   offset: _PagePosition#edc3e(offset: null, range: null..null, viewport: null, ScrollableState,
flutter:   PageScrollPhysics -> AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics -> BouncingScrollPhysics,
flutter:   IdleScrollActivity#95217, ScrollDirection.idle)
flutter:   anchor: 0.0
flutter: This RenderObject had the following child:
flutter:   RenderSliverFillViewport#5d322 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#64551 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#64551 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIgnorePointer#cca00 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#498e5 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#a32d0 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#cbf64 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderScrollSemantics#11d99 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderStack#d9de7 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#554a3 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#1d6d0 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#b279d NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIgnorePointer#e430d NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderStack#e8e8f NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderDecoratedBox#a3175 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFractionalTranslation#4ca11 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFractionalTranslation#0d592 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#6ed00 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#7d38e NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderOffstage#4e5b5 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderStack#4e841 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderTheatre#f534f NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#85a31 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderAbsorbPointer#a08a9 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#f45f1 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#5f6ee NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#6ed00 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#5f6ee
flutter: Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'visible' was called on null.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#5dcca
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#6ed00 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#5f6ee
```

**My code is:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Components/Tutorial.dart';

    class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
    }

    class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(38.0),
                child: Text(
                    'Title',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      decoration: TextDecoration.none
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Tutorial()
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

This only happens when I insert Tutorial inside a Column. I try many things but I don't understand why the crash!

**And the file with the Tutorial class:**

```
Import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DotsIndicator extends AnimatedWidget {
  DotsIndicator({
    this.controller,
    this.itemCount,
    this.onPageSelected,
    this.color: Colors.white,
  }) : super(listenable: controller);

  /// The PageController that this DotsIndicator is representing.
  final PageController controller;

  /// The number of items managed by the PageController
  final int itemCount;

  /// Called when a dot is tapped
  final ValueChanged<int> onPageSelected;

  /// The color of the dots.
  ///
  /// Defaults to `Colors.white`.
  final Color color;

  // The base size of the dots
  static const double _kDotSize = 8.0;

  // The increase in the size of the selected dot
  static const double _kMaxZoom = 2.0;

  // The distance between the center of each dot
  static const double _kDotSpacing = 25.0;

  Widget _buildDot(int index) {
    double selectedness = Curves.easeOut.transform(
      max(
        0.0,
        1.0 - ((controller.page ?? controller.initialPage) - index).abs(),
      ),
    );
    double zoom = 1.0 + (_kMaxZoom - 1.0) * selectedness;
    return Container(
      width: _kDotSpacing,
      child: Center(
        child: Material(
          color: color,
          type: MaterialType.circle,
          child: Container(
            width: _kDotSize * zoom,
            height: _kDotSize * zoom,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () => onPageSelected(index),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: List<Widget>.generate(itemCount, _buildDot),
    );
  }
}

class Tutorial extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => TutorialState();
}

class TutorialState extends State<Tutorial> {
  final _controller = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.5);

  static const _kDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 300);

  static const _kCurve = Curves.ease;

  final _kArrowColor = Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8);

  static onTap(index) {
    print("$index selected.");
  }

  final List<Widget> _pages = <Widget>[
    FlutterLogo(colors: Colors.blue),
    FlutterLogo(style: FlutterLogoStyle.stacked, colors: Colors.red),
    FlutterLogo(style: FlutterLogoStyle.horizontal, colors: Colors.green),
  ];

  Widget _buildPageItem(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Page(page: _pages[index], idx: index);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        PageView.builder(
          physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          controller: _controller,
          itemCount: _pages.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return _buildPageItem(context, index % _pages.length);
          },
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 0.0,
          left: 0.0,
          right: 0.0,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.grey[800].withOpacity(0.5),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Center(
              child: DotsIndicator(
                controller: _controller,
                itemCount: _pages.length,
                onPageSelected: (int page) {
                  _controller.animateToPage(
                    page,
                    duration: _kDuration,
                    curve: _kCurve,
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  final page;
  final idx;

  Page({
    @required this.page,
    @required this.idx,
  });

  onTap() {
    print("${this.idx} selected.");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0)
    );
  }
}
```

**What is the error? What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: You are having a list inside row widget do you want horizontal scroll effect ??

Answer (score 1):

you need to use [Expanded](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) for the tutorial Widget

[image]

```
  Expanded(child: Tutorial())
```

Answer (score 0):

try change column to listview

```
ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(38.0),
          child: Text(
            'Title',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
          ),
        ),
        Tutorial()
      ],
    )
```